# Application Window in Eclipse with WindowBuilder

Tags: java, swing, gwt, swt, windowbuilder

I am relatively new in Java programming, I have been using Eclipse with WindowBuilder but I don't get what is the difference between using a `JFrame` or Application Window in Swing Designer. Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Well there's not much of a difference between the two since the only thing unique about the JFrame wizard is that it voluntarily creates a JFrame subclass. On the other hand, a subclass of Object that has a JFrame is automatically created in the Application Window wizard from the Swing Designer. The JFrame Wizard is always more favorable to use in my opinion.